# Grab events from Eventbrite API with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, eventbrite

So I'm unable to find any examples and the example used on the npm package `README` throws me an error.

So I'm using https://github.com/Datahero/node-eventbrite

I require it in `app.js`. I create the token variable and place my token in there.

I add this piece of snippet in

```
try {
    var api = eventbriteAPI({
        token: eventbrite_token,
        version : 'v3'
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message); // the options are missing, this function throws an error.
}
```

So on the `README` file it says the next line of code should be something like (replacing the `user_id:` with my user id).

```
api.owned_events({ user_id: 30 }, function (error, data) {
    if (error)
        console.log(error.message);
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // Do something with your data!
});
```

I get the error `TypeError: api.owned_events is not a function`

Basically I'm trying to get a list of events based on the location from the Eventbrite API via node. But I'm unable to even query from node and get what I want back. Has anyone any resources or can offer help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an error on the README file, api should be declared outside the try/catch block:

```
var api;

try {
     api = eventbriteAPI({
        token: eventbrite_token,
        version : 'v3'
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}

api.owned_events({ user_id: 30 }, function (error, data) {
    if (error)
        console.log(error.message);
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // Do something with your data!
});
```